# More friendly word for "enterprise"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms, euphemisms

This is a toughy, but I'm looking for a word that doesn't have the connotations of "enterprise," "corporate" or "national account." Something that will get the idea of multi-unit businesses across in a simple, pleasant way (doesn't necessarily have to be a single word.)

Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1):

I think that :

> *Service  and/or productive activity*

may convey the idea of a multi- unit business without the connotation of a corporation.

Answer (score -1):

- Activity
- Collaboration
- Collaborative effort
- Cooperative
- Initiative
- Partnering organizations